# How to prevent call back call when asp button clicked?

Tags: asp.net

I have this image asp button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnUploadCoordinates"  OnClientClick="return ConfirmUploadCoordinates(); " ImageUrl="../Images/cloud-upload.png"  Style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"  ValidationGroup="Clear" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadCoordinates_Click" />
```

Is it possible to prevent postback call when I click on the element?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
OnClientClick="return ConfirmUploadCoordinates();
```

should change to

```
 OnClientClick="return ConfirmUploadCoordinates(event);
```

and then in your Javascript code

```
function ConfirmUploadCoordinates(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventdefault();
  return false;
}
```

or whatever your ConfirmUploadCoordinates function needs to do...

HTH